# Positioning A Image Over A Div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I have the following div laid out with a music note that is supposed to be stretched out ontop of the div box and I'm not sure the correct properties to apply so that it matches my design composition.

```
<div id="teachings" class="row important">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <h2>My Teachings</h2>
        <p>Music is an art that encourages many different types of learning.  Through my lessons students will learn how to play flute and piano. Students will learn how to read and notate music so they can write music and be able to play or sing anything they wish.  They also learn about different cultures and people through the music that they play. They can use the time that they perform to build confidence in themselves. Some students may find that they enjoy music at a high level and wish to continue to use music in the rest of their lives, as a career or added to another career.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="assets/images/music-note.png" alt="Music Note">
    </div>  
</div>

.important {
    background-color: #9999FF;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#teachings img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[image: Teachings][image: Design Comp]

Comment: use `class='img-responsive'` for your `img` property. Remove all the absolute properties from your class. `<img src="assets/images/music-note.png" alt="Music Note" class="img-responsive">`

Comment: That doesn't position the img as I have it exactly in my design.

Comment: which one of them is your design?

Comment: The second one is my design.

Comment: So what I"m trying to say is the note should be taller than the size of the div its on top of.

Comment: Cool. Please provide us with a working demo so we can try it faster :)

Comment: dev.cassandradavidsonflautist.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

To position the image out of it's containing div like the attached design. You should position it absolutely and center it vertical, then you need to specify a certain height.

```
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.img-wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -75px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadeed/pen/345fae518a103a8e9d02452203ee60f2)**

Comment: If I do that then it becomes fully placed inside the div which I mentioned isn't what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Which is funny because in your first response you told me to not absolute position it.

Comment: @user3732216 Yeah because your question wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can center it without giving extra top margins in this manner:

```
.img-wrapper {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}

.img-wrapper img {
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```